# jQuery modal popup not showing element value

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

After opening a Bootstrap 4.0 modal in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor page, the jQuery `shown.bs.modal` event is not showing the element value in the modal. But, logging the assigned value to the console shows it correctly. And using `show.bs.modal` instead still doesn't work. Is the modal popping up prematurely? What could be wrong?

**HTML Modal:**

```
<div id="eventModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#eventModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#eventModal #eventTitle').val("Sample Title");
    console.log($('#eventModal #eventTitle').val()); // This shows correctly.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following methods:

1. `.text()` - Sets or returns the text content of selected elements
2. `.html()` - Sets or returns the content of selected elements (example : including HTML markup)
3. `.val()` - Sets or returns the value of form fields

So, you can use :

```
$('#eventModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#eventTitle').text("Sample Title");        
}
```

Comment: Using `.text()` worked. Thanks!